# How to use fileUpload Interceptor along with other interceptor Stack?

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, struts2, interceptorstack

Here is my `struts.xml` configuration file in which I have a login interceptor. I want to use different file upload interceptor, in different action with different file type, and maximum size as given. But the problem is here: It's always taking the default `maximumSize` and `allowedType`.  Where I am doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

    <struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
    value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
    value="ApplicationResources" />

<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles"
            class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types>
    
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="nlogin" class="com.picvik.interceptor.LoginInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="nlogin"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="validation"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow"/>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
    <!-- <default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>  -->
   
    <global-results>
        <result name="login" type="tiles">/login.tiles</result>
    </global-results>

    
    <action name="home" 
        class="com.picvik.action.HomeAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/home.tiles</result>
        <result name="error" type="tiles">/welcome.tiles</result>
    </action>
    <action name="registration" 
        class="com.picvik.action.RegisterAction" method="execute">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/register.tiles</result>
    </action>
    <action name="register" 
        class="com.picvik.action.RegisterAction" method="register">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/registerverify.tiles</result>
        <result name="error" type="tiles">/register.tiles</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">/register.tiles</result>
    </action>
    <action name="verify" 
        class="com.picvik.action.RegisterAction" method="verify">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/login.tiles</result>
        <result name="error" type="tiles">/registerverify.tiles</result>
    </action>
    
     <action name="login" class="com.picvik.action.LoginAction">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/home.tiles</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">/login.tiles</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="dologin" class="com.picvik.action.LoginAction" method="login">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/home.tiles</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">/login.tiles</result>
    </action>

    <action name="logout" class="com.picvik.action.LoginAction" method="logout">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/login.tiles</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="viewprofile" class="com.picvik.action.ViewProfileAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/viewprofile.tiles</result>
    </action>
    <action name="editprofile" class="com.picvik.action.ViewProfileAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/editprofile.tiles</result>
    </action>
    <action name="saveprofile" class="com.picvik.action.ViewProfileAction" method = "saveProfile">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/home.tiles</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">/editprofile.tiles</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="changeprofilephoto" class="com.picvik.action.ChangeProfilePhotoAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/changephoto.tiles</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">/changephoto.tiles</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="uploadprofilephoto"
            class="com.picvik.action.ChangeProfilePhotoAction" method="uploadProfilePhoto">
         <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>
            <param name="allowedTypes">
                image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
            </param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type= "redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">viewprofile</param>
        </result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">/changephoto.tiles</result>
    </action>
    <!-- video upload-->
    <action name="videouploader"
            class="com.picvik.action.UploadVideoAction" method="execute">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/videoupload.tiles</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="uploadvideo"
            class="com.picvik.action.UploadVideoAction" method="uploadVideo">
         <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="maximumSize">209715200</param>
            <param name="allowedTypes">
                video/mp4
            </param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type= "redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">editvideo</param>
        </result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">/videoupload.tiles</result>
    </action>
    <action name="editvideo"
            class="com.picvik.action.UploadVideoAction" method="editVideo">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type= "redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">home</param>
        </result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">/editvideo.tiles</result>
    </action>
    <action name="savevideos"
            class="com.picvik.action.UploadVideoAction" method="saveVideo">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type= "redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">listVideo</param>
        </result>
        <result name="error" type="tiles">/editvideo.tiles</result>
    </action>
    <!-- video upload ends here-->
    
    <!-- photo upload -->
    <action name="photouploader"
            class="com.picvik.action.UploadPhotoAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/photoupload.tiles</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="uploadphoto"
            class="com.picvik.action.UploadPhotoAction" method="uploadPhoto">
         <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="maximumSize">20971520</param>
            <param name="allowedTypes">
                image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
            </param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type= "redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">editphoto</param>
        </result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">/photoupload.tiles</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="editphoto"
            class="com.picvik.action.UploadPhotoAction" method="editPhoto">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type= "redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">home</param>
        </result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">/editphoto.tiles</result>
    </action>
    <action name="savephotos"
            class="com.picvik.action.UploadPhotoAction" method="savePhoto">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type= "redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">listalbum</param>
        </result>
        <result name="error" type="tiles">/editphoto.tiles</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="listalbum"
            class="com.picvik.action.ViewAlbumAction" method="listAlbum">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/listalbum.tiles</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="listphoto"
            class="com.picvik.action.ViewAlbumAction" method="listPhoto">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/listphoto.tiles</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="listalbumphoto"
            class="com.picvik.action.ViewAlbumAction" method="listAlbumPhoto">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/listalbumphoto.tiles</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="viewphoto"
            class="com.picvik.action.ViewAlbumAction" method="viewPhoto">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/viewphoto.tiles</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="commentonphoto"
            class="com.picvik.action.CommentAction" method="commentOnPhoto">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type= "redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">listphoto</param>
        </result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="commentonalbum"
            class="com.picvik.action.CommentAction" method="commentOnAlbum">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type= "redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">listalbum</param>
        </result>
    </action>
    
</package>
```

Comment: Do you mean the validation is not working?

Comment: validation is working but for all action maximumsize is validating as default, its not taking the parameter values I am giving in a particular action.

Comment: also its not giving any error when I am trying to upload file type which is not in allowed list of files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following configuration property to override the defaults

```
struts.multipart.maxSize=2097152
```

that is taken from the default.properties. Note without `0` at the end.

Check the documentation and examples how to use [`fileUpload`](http://struts.apache.org/core-developers/file-upload.html) interceptor.